# Generate Questions From TextNodes

Tags: evaluation, large-language-model, llama-index

I am trying to become familiar with llamaIndex and it's retrieval evaluation API.
I created this quick program to fetch a bunch of paragraphs from a db and converted them into TextNode objects. Then I passed them to this method:

```
from llama_index.evaluation import generate_question_context_pairs

eval_questions = generate_question_context_pairs(
        summary_nodes, llm=llm, num_questions_per_chunk=1
    )
```

here I assumed each of the nodes would be treated as a single chunk it would generate a single question per node. However, the output contained 150 questions for 25 TextNodes. Some nodes had many questions and others had only 1.

I am a little confused here. Is a node not a chunk and if not how can I restrict llamaIndex to only generate 1 question per provided Node?